# What to expect from Trello desktop notifications?

Tags: trello, notifications

I am a member and subscriber to a card in Trello with a due date and time. When the due date in the card goes red, I am expecting notifications both in Chrome and in the upper right hand corner of the Trello-tab in Chrome. I do not get any of the two. Can anyone please help me understand? Do I have the wrong expectations?

Details:

- I have turned off Email-notifications. We are using Trello to skip internal Emails.
- I have turned on Desktop-notifications.
- I have checked that Chrome allows Trello to make notifications.
- I have checked in Chrome on multiple PCs with multiple versions of Windows installed.

Answer (score 1):

Trello only generates notifications about cards 24 hours before the card's due date. You also must be a member of the card, or subscribed to the card, list, or board.

For more information, check the article in their support portal: http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/993808-notifications-are-not-working

There's also a card in the Trello development board about notifications: https://trello.com/c/naE1Cxcm/1008-notifications-for-upcoming-due-dates

Comment: I now understand why certain notifications did not appear: They had been set less than 24 hours ahead. I had missed the 24 hour time limit. Question answered. Thank you Kelvin. Jesper